# posting to wordpress.com blog using codeigniter

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, wordpress.com

Hi I am trying to develop an app that could post to wordpress from my website…..is there any way that I can use something like oauth to authenticate visitors on wordpress and then post to the wordpress.com blog ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this through XML-RPC interface to wordpress.com, but your users must provide their login information, such as [Flickr](http://en.support.wordpress.com/images/flickr-photos/).

You should check the corresponding [class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/xmlrpc.html) in CI.

Comment: hey do u have any idea how to enable/install xml-rpc in php. I am looking at my phpinfo and I cannot see it .... thanks for the help

Comment: Codeigniter has a class for working with XML-RPC. Their only dependence is xml parser, which is by default since PHP 4, so you do not have to install anything.

Just read the links, to begin implementation.